# Installation macOS High Sierra shows Prohibitory Symbol

Tags: macos, ssd, installation, macos-highsierra

The HDD from my daughter's Macbook white mid 2010 is very old and running terribly slow, so I bought a Samsung 870 EVO 500GB SSD to replace it. Then I downloaded a install Mac OS El Capitan app.zip file from archive.org. I made a bootable installation USB from it according to this [page](https://www.lifewire.com/create-bootable-os-x-el-capitan-installer-2259939). The installation took about 2 hours and it was ok, but as soon as I retarted the macbook, it was showing a Prohibitory Symbol. I could only push and hold the power button to force the macbook to shut down, then pushed the power button again to start, after that, it could boot normally into El Capitan.
In El Capitan I found MacOS High Sierra in Apple store and upgraded the system into High Sierra. The installation stopped twice, showing Prohibitory Symbol, but after shuting down and restarting, the installation of High Sierra was finished and booted into High Sierra. But after I restarted the system it booted to another Prohibitory Symbol. The only way for me to get into the system is by shutting down and booting the machine again. Though I don't need to restart macbook very often, it is still annoying. Does anybody know how to get rid of this Prohibitory Symbol?
The format of SSD is APFS. Does this problem have something to do with SSD? Need firmware updating? I searched in the internet whole afternoon with no luck.
Thank you in advance for any insight and help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, this is really confusing. El Capitan has no clue what APFS is, cannot see it at all, so cannot install to it or run from it. High Sierra will only install to HFS+, which it then insists on converting to APFS as part of the install, after which it can read & boot from it. Part of the update to High Sierra on an older MBP will install a firmware update, enabling it to use an SSD. …anyway, what you're describing could best be explained by a bad SATA cable. First step - get a new one.

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin. I remember I formated the SSD first with HFS+ before installing El Capitan. Then the installation automatically formatted the SSD into APFS. The Sata cable for 2,5 inch SSD is quite tiny, don't know if I can get one. At this stage, the macbook is useble, since it really doesn't need to be restart often. It's just a little bit uncomfortable. But thank you. You wrote "Part of the update to High Sierra on an older MBP will install a firmware update", so the installation did install a firmware update for it to better work with SSD?

Comment: If you went from El Cap to HS on an internal drive, then you got the firmware update. I still suspect the SATA cable. You can still get parts - https://www.ifixit.com/Parts/MacBook